# Cartan integral formula for a p-adic group?

Tags: p-adic-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ denote a reductive group over a local field $F$. Suppose that $G$ is split over $F$ and fix a maximal (split) torus $A$. Let $A^+$ denote a Weyl chamber in $A$ and let $K$ be a suitable maximal compact subgroup of $G$.
Then it is known that a Cartan decomposition holds:
$$
G=KA^+K.
$$
Hence there is a weight function $w\ge 0$ such that for the Haar-integrals one has
$$
\int_G f(x)\ dx=\int_K\int_{A^+}\int_K f(kal)\ w(a)\ dk\ da\ dl.
$$
If the field is archimedean, the function $w$ can be explicitly computed as a product over positive roots, see Knapp's book on page 141.

My question is this: Is there a similar explicit formula for $w$ in the non-archimedean case?
Normalising the measures so that the compact open subgroups get measure 1 we see that
$$
w(a)=|K\backslash KaK|,
$$
but I don't know whether that's of any help.

Comment: Pretty sure you know - your formula gives $w(a)$ as a product of an explicit power of $q$ times the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points on a partial flag variety. Giving a not-so-educated comment, I'd say the resulting non-trivial combinatorics is  probably essential in p-adic integrals?

Comment: @Cheng-Chiang Tsai: The way I (kind of) solved this was through the building. I need a formula for the number of vertices in distance $n$ from a given vertex. Until now, I don't have such a formula for all buildings, but I can do separate formulas for type A,B,C and so on. The result is pretty explicit and good enough for my purposes. The drawback is the case distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to Anton for a uniform proof of your formula: note that $K\backslash KaK\cong(a^{-1}Ka\cap K)\backslash K$. Let $\pi:K\rightarrow G(\mathbb{F}_q)$  be the natural quotient map, $K_1:=\ker(\pi)$ and $P:=\pi(a^{-1}Ka\cap K)$. Then $P$ is the $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of the parabolic subgroup of $G$ determined by the walls that $a$ lies on. We have
$$|(a^{-1}Ka\cap K)\backslash K|=|P\backslash G(\mathbb{F}_q)|\cdot|(a^{-1}Ka\cap K_1)\backslash K_1|.$$
Let $\mathfrak{K}$ be the Lie algebra of $K$ and likewise for $\mathfrak{K}_1$. Choose Haar measures for the group and Lie algebra so that $\mu(K_1)=\mu(\mathfrak{K}_1)$. Since $a^{-1}Ka\cap K_1$ and $K_1$ are open compact, we have $|(a^{-1}Ka\cap K_1)\backslash K_1|=\mu(a^{-1}Ka\cap K_1)\backslash\mu(K_1)=\mu(a^{-1}\mathfrak{K}a\cap\mathfrak{K}_1)\backslash\mu(\mathfrak{K}_1)=|(a^{-1}\mathfrak{K}a\cap\mathfrak{K}_1)\backslash \mathfrak{K}_1|$.

Identifying $a$ as an element in the positive Weyl chamber in the cocharacter lattice, the last term is $q$ to the power of $\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi^+}\max(\langle a,\alpha\rangle-1,0)$, while the roots of $P$ are those $\alpha\in\Phi$ with $\langle a,\alpha\rangle\le 0$.